# Displaying multiple instances of a component in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, rendering

I'm completely new to vue.js and as part of my learning I'm just trying to create a button, that when each time this button is pressed, an annotation (a draggable text box where users can input their text) will be created. This is what I currently have :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button v-on:click="addAnnotation()">Add annotation</button>
    <div v-for="(annotation, index) in annotations" :key="index">
      <component :is="annotation">
      </component>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DraggableAnnotation from "./components/DraggableAnnotation.vue";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    DraggableAnnotation,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      annotations: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addAnnotation: function () {
      this.annotations.push({ DraggableAnnotation });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

I'm not very sure if my implementation is correct. Each time the button is pressed, I want to create an annotation, and add it to the list of annotations. Then, I'm trying to render the list of annotations using v-for to display all the annotations to the user, but I'm not sure what to pass in as the key as I don't have any props for the DraggableAnnotation component.

When I press my addAnnotation button, I get this error in the console log.

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <App>
         <Root>
```

Edit : defined index in here

```
<div v-for="(annotation, index) in annotations" :key="index">
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it error cuz index not definded

```
<div v-for="annotation in annotations" :key="index">
```

instead

```
<div v-for="(annotation, index) in annotations" :key="index">
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting an issue when I'm trying to add an annotation. I've editted the question at the bottom